# I have a string list and i want to show a Icon according a word

Tags: flutter

I have a list 'Life', 'Car', 'Car' and I want to return a favorite icon if the word is life and a car icon if the word is a car. This is the class that I made

```
class IcoImage extends Icon {
  final List<String> entries;
  final int i = 0;

  IcoImage({Key key, this.entries}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    return entries[i].toString()=='Life'?Icons.favorite_border:Icons.directions_car;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not store the icons in your assets folder and then access them like this :

```
class IcoImage extends Icon {
  final List<String> entries;
  final int i = 0;

  IcoImage({Key key, this.entries}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    return Image.asset(
                    'assets/images/${entries[i].toString()}.png');
    }
  }
}
```

or instead of passing a List you can pass a map

```
List<Map<String, IconData>> _myIcons = [
    {
      'name': 'Favorite',
      'icon': Icons.favorite,
    },
    {
      'name': 'Car',
      'icon': Icons.directions_car,
    },

];
```

and return this instead `Icon(_myIcons[index]['icon']);`